# Versioned classes appears to be created by REGASM - how to use them?

Tags: com, com-interop

When I register a .NET assembly enabled for COM interop using the REGASM tool, the tool creates a separate registry key for each component version. For example, I get:

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{myCLSID}\InprocServer32\1.0.0.0`

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{myCLSID}\InprocServer32\1.1.0.0`

etc.

Each of these registry contains roughly the same structure values as it is under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{}\InprocServer32, except that the entries point to different locations, depending on the component version. The HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{myCLSID}\InprocServer32 apparently contains the latest registered version, and that's what COM consumers will normally use, of course, and they ignore the rest.

This structure apparently allows different versions of the component coexist on the same computer (I know it is against the originally specified COM rules). I would like to use it, but I could not find any documentation about it anywhere in the Microsoft documentation or Googling for it. Does anybody know? I am looking for something like CoCreateInstance/CoCreateInstanceEx with the version specifier.

Thanks

Comment: That's not possible.  These keys are used to help the CLR find the highest version of an assembly that's compatible with the loaded RuntimeVersion.

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense and finally explains the purpose of this. So my understanding is that it allows multiple implementations of the same component to coexist, but those that get ultimately executed are supposed to be equivalent in terms of functionality (not really different versions), just possibly built for different runtime.

Comment: I've recently encountered this issue after I foolishly tried to make sure all my assemblies followed Semantic Versioning. If I'm developing and go back to previous branches, my registry will contain newer versions that aren't found and because I can't specify a version in CoCreateInstance - they fail. What a nightmare.